# How to disable ECDH key-reuse on IIS 10?

Tags: ssl, iis

A SSL Report from SSL Labs for a domain of mine indicates that ECDH key-reuse (ECDH public server param reuse) is happening on the IIS 10 (Windows Server 2016) with TLS 1.2. I have verified it with TestSSLServer and testssl.sh.

I am not able to find a solution on the big Internet to disable the ECDH key-reuse on IIS 10. It does not seem to work with MaximumCacheSize nor ServerCacheTime.

Can anyone of you help with a solution to disable the ECDH key-reuse? (The web server do not reuse DH keys, even though some cipher suites with DHE have been activated.)

Thank you!

Comment: This is apparently a million dollar question no one I have asked so far have an answer for..

If you can answer this one, I owe you one hour of work.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable this via Registry Editor.
Just go to `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\ECDH` create a value (*DWORD (32-bit)*) named `EphemKeyReuseTime` and set it to `0`.

Microsoft tends to cache the key and regenerate it periodically.

Comment: "Could you provide us with some support information, such as a reference please?"